# Getting Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, springfox, springfox-boot-starter

I am getting error:

> Application run failed
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

I am using below dependencies:

```
id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.11"
id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.15.RELEASE"
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.21"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.6.21"
implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0")
    implementation("io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.1.9")
    implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("com.shazam:shazamcrest:0.11")
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.4.10")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10")
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6")
    implementation("org.valiktor:valiktor-core:0.11.0")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.10.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.10.2")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:5.1.0+")
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.8.3")
    implementation("am.ik.yavi:yavi:0.4.0")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-slf4j:1.3.9")
    implementation("org.zalando:logbook-spring-boot-starter:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.sentry:sentry-spring-boot-starter:1.7.30")
    implementation("io.sentry:sentry-logback:1.7.30")
    implementation ("org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.5")
    implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:3.1.2")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
```

I have tried with multiple solutions including adding
`spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy=ANT_PATH_MATCHER` to application.properties but none of them worked.

Full stacktrace:

```
RROR [      main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:937)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.abc.xyz.XYZServiceRouterKt.main(XYZRouter.kt:29)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.getPatterns(WebMvcPatternsRequestConditionWrapper.java:56)
    at springfox.documentation.RequestHandler.sortedPaths(RequestHandler.java:113)
    at springfox.documentation.spi.service.contexts.Orderings.lambda$byPatternsCondition$3(Orderings.java:89)
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.requestHandlers(WebMvcRequestHandlerProvider.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.withDefaults(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:107)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.buildContext(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:91)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.bootstrapDocumentationPlugins(AbstractDocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:82)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:100)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178)
```

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: @M.Deinum added full stacktrace.